# Tabulate Command Stata

Tags: frequency, stata

I don't know if Stata can do this but I use the `tabulate` command a lot in order to find frequencies. For instance, I have a success variable which takes on values 0 to 1 and I would like to know the success rate for a certain group of observations ie `tab success if group==1`. I was wondering if I can do sort of the inverse of this operation.  That is, I would like to know if I can find a value of "group" for which the frequency is greater than or equal to 15% for example.

Is there a command that does this?

Thanks

As an example

```
sysuse auto
gen success=mpg<29
```

Now I want to find the value of price such that the frequency of the success variable is greater than 75% for example.

Comment: Your question contains its own answer. You can do what you know how to do because you can write down a condition that `if` can interpret using known variables and/or constants. So, you need to be able to do that. Usually some data manipulations would be required to get to that point. Depending on details, there may be partial exceptions e.g. check out `groups` from SSC.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying to be honest.  I want to know if there is a command that instead of telling me the frequency, I can put in the frequency and it will give me the value for the group. Is that possible?

Comment: I am saying (e.g.) if you have a variable for frequency, then naturally you can specify a condition using that variable. Which part of "check out `groups` from SSC" did you not understand?

Comment: Anyone not familiar with SSC should follow `help ssc`.

Comment: I could figure out follow groups from ssc. I just didn't understand anything else you said.

Comment: "I have no idea what you're saying to be honest" was either incorrect or exaggerated then; neither way of reacting to suggestions will elicit help efficiently.

Comment: I apologize. I didnt understand what you said other than the groups part. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Nick:

```
ssc install groups 
sysuse auto 
count
   74
#return list optional
local nobs=r(N) # r(N) gives total observation 

groups  rep78, sel(f >(0.15*`r(N)')) #gives the group for which freq >15 % 

  +---------------------------------+
  | rep78   Freq.   Percent    % <= |
  |---------------------------------|
  |     3      30     43.48   57.97 |
  |     4      18     26.09   84.06 |
  +---------------------------------+
groups  rep78, sel(f >(0.10*`nobs'))# more than 10 %

  +----------------------------------+
  | rep78   Freq.   Percent     % <= |
  |----------------------------------|
  |     2       8     11.59    14.49 |
  |     3      30     43.48    57.97 |
  |     4      18     26.09    84.06 |
  |     5      11     15.94   100.00 |
  +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for pushing this forwards. As you have created local macro `nobs` containing the count, you should use it. `r(N)` could, at least in other circumstances, contain something else or nothing at all after a separate command. Also `groups` lets you select on percent frequencies.

Comment: So this just lists the frequency of a variable. I am wondering if I can find the frequency of a success variable happening at a certain level of another variable. For instance, what is the value of the variable rep78 such that the frequency of success is greater than .15.

Comment: You need to  define what is success rate here?

Comment: @Nick. Thank you. I have corrected that. I will let the OP to work on the percentage part.

Comment: `groups` lets you work with two or more variables. You need to specify an example using a dataset we can all access, either one provided with Stata or one you give yourself. It remains obscure whether success rate is for you a variable in the dataset or something calculated from the dataset.

Comment: "For instance, I have a success variable which takes on values 0 to 1" is in my original post. As an example take success is when mpg <29 in the auto data set.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include an example. sorry if im not being clear. I'm reading the help groups page but I can't seem to figure it out from there.

Comment: Thanks for the focus on the auto dataset. But `price` has 74 distinct values for 74 observations. So `mpg < 29` is just 1 or 0 in those 74 categories and the answer is some variant on `tab price if mpg < 29`. I doubt that is your question....

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question/situation, but I believe this might be useful. You can `egen` a variable that is equal to the mean of success, by group, and then see which observations have the value for mean(success) that you're looking for.

```
egen avgsuccess = mean(success), by(group)
tab group if avgsuccess >= 0.15
list group if avgsuccess >= 0.15
```

Does that accomplish what you want?